# Salesforce, using picklist programmatically. Is it possible to "select" a picklistEntry

Tags: salesforce

Wondering if it's possible to set a picklistEntry as "selected" programmatically. I know usually a user will be doing this, however, I want to do this programmatically because I'm sending an email to salesforce, and the value is already there.

Scenario:
Send an email to salesforce that will create a custom object. The email will have the field for picklist as well as the picklistEntry.value() in a string format.
ie. "Programming Languages: PHP, JS, RoR"
I have it splitting up into "Programming Languages" and "PHP" "JS" "RoR".

Inside salesforce, there is a multipicklist(multi-select) for Programming Languages, for PHP, JS, RoR and more.

How do I make sure that the custom object field "Programming_Languages" will have PHP, JS, RoR selected and not the other ones?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will take a string value, separated by semicolons. So your programming languages might looks something like:

```
object__c.Programming_Languages__c = 'PHP; JS; RoR';
```

Comment: Thanks, I was testing if that was the case, and it appeared to work. I just forgot to post back my result. Thanks!